# Using a value defined in one class in a second class

Tags: java, eclipse

I have a class, called L_HullMA3, where I have defined a value "MA".

```
public class L_HullMA_V3 extends Study {
    enum Values { MA }
}
```

I want to use that value in another class.

I tried both of these solutions I found:

```
Double Ma = L_HullMA_V3.MA;
debug ("yaaaaaaaaaay!!!" + Ma);
```

and

```
L_HullMA_V3  Hull = new L_HullMA_V3();
Double Ma = Hull.MA;
debug ("yaaaaaaaaaay !!!" + Ma);
```

Eclipse gives me a  "error: duplicate class" when I try to compile. 
I am only taking my first steps in java, so I am probably missing something obvious.

Comment: do you have two classes with same name, in same package? It seems you tried several versions, it may be that you copypasted one, and forgot to rename/delete the original?

Comment: I checked and rechecked. That is not the case

Comment: inner classes as well?

Comment: Found it ! seems I had the "package" wrong at the beginning of the file. I changed it into "package study_examples;" (where my second class also 'lives') and it works now. Thanks for the gentle push @AsierAranbarri !

Comment: you're welcome!! glad you could fix it. Now lets take a good martini and vodka to celebrate